# Java: KeyListener not detected in game

Tags: java, keylistener

For my assignment I have to add movement to a character in a game. The way this works is simple: If they press left they change the direction to left and if they press right they change to right right (the character is always moving).

The way this works is every half second or so the game calls an `update()` method where it redraws etc. It will then ask the character if they want to move in a new direction by calling  `updateMoveDirection()` on the character.

I've tested it and this method is definitely being called regularly as expected. However, when I add a `KeyListener` to lookout for the left and right clicks then these are not detected. I think it has something to do with the focus of the class? However, since this class has no graphical element then I'm not sure how it can request focus?

```
public void updateMoveDirection() {
    KeyListener k = new KeyListener() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            System.out.println("KEY");
            if(arg0.equals(KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)){
                System.out.println("LEFT");

            }
            if(arg0.equals(KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)){
                System.out.println("RIGHT");

            }

        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `addKeyListener()`?

Comment: @NathanielJones where can I call this since I am not adding it to a GUI component like a Frame etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quiet sure how your game is setup. Usually it is enough to have one KeyListener attached to the JFrame, JWindow, JComponent or Canvas (or more generally the Swing class you use for drawing. The code above looks like you would try to add one KeyListener for every game object you want to be reacting to the input. Technically possible but not the besr approach.

But more likely your problem is a different one. Be aware that Java, for some reason, CAN have troubles to detect multiple pressed keys at once. Also, keypressed is called often as long it is pressed.

I would recommend:

1. Create a class which implements the Keylistener interface and has access to the character and everything else you want to controll. Let's call that class InputController.
2. Add the InputController as listener to the swing component.
3. In the InputController use keyReleased and keyTyped instead of keyPressed
4. Add a boolean member for each key (e.g. boolean isLeftDown) plus matching setter methods
5. In the InputController you now can use the setters of the character to ser the values and in the update method check if they are down or not

Edit: 
Or you can place the booleans in the InputController and give the character access to it. Then it fits the "the update reads the input" more exactly

Comment: Thanks for the input @monty but in the description of the project it says that the updateMovement method :  "Reads keyboard input and changes the snake's direction as necessary.". This seems to me like it should be handled within this method rather than in an external class?

Also the Swing components of the game are handled externally in a seperate jar file so I cannot change them directly.

Comment: @monty Is correct about using a class for this rather than putting it it the method. Also, even if you don't edit the Swing components directly, can't you access them and call, for instance, `myWindow.addKeyListener();` from within your class?

Comment: @NathanielJones just noticed you can do that. Thanks for the help guys!

Comment: @monty ah just noticed you can add it from the external library! Thanks for the help! Awarded

Comment: @John if you (have to) use external libraries it is wise to mention that in the original question. Chances are high that they already cover input handling and may offer other ways to read the inputs (and maybe thats the way your teacher wants to see). This answer was tailored to a Java game from scratch scenario.